# How to create the zip file from the selected rows of datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am displaying certain elements from .xml files into a `DataGridView` and it's working fine.

Here is the code to select the xml files

```
//Browse Folder
private void Btn_SelectFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Rows.Clear();
                dt.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(bool));
                dt.Columns.Add("File_Name");
                dt.Columns.Add("Vendor_Name");
                dt.Columns.Add("Vendor_ID");
                dt.Columns.Add("Date_Range", typeof(DateTime));

                lbl_Path.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.xml");

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("cfdi:Emisor");
                XmlNodeList nodes1 = doc.GetElementsByTagName("cfdi:Comprobante");

                foreach (string tot_file in files)
                {
                    doc.Load(tot_file);
                    string FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tot_file);

                    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string Name = nodes[i].Attributes["Nombre"].Value;
                        string ID = nodes[i].Attributes["Rfc"].Value;
                        string Date = nodes1[i].Attributes["Fecha"].Value;

                        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                        row["File_Name"] = FileName;
                        row["Vendor_Name"] = Name;
                        row["Vendor_ID"] = ID;
                        row["Date_Range"] = Date;
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }

                XML_Grid.DataSource = dt;
                txt_FileName.ReadOnly = false;
                txt_Name.ReadOnly = false;
                txt_ID.ReadOnly = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Now what i want is to select the rows from `DataGridView` and create the zip file of selected files.

I have tried this code to create the zip file:

```
//Create Zip
private void Btn_SaveZip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string folderToZip = lbl_Path.Text;

        string zipFile = saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".zip";

        using (ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipFile, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderToZip);
            FileInfo[] filesToArchive = di.GetFiles();

            if (filesToArchive != null && filesToArchive.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo fileToArchive in filesToArchive)
                {
                    zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileToArchive.FullName, fileToArchive.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                }
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Zip File Successfully Created", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine and creating zip file But it's directly checking the files from the path and creating zip file of that folder.

How to select the files from `DataGridview` not directly from the folder and create the zip file of selected files.

My Form:
[image]

Any help would be helpful for me, I've been trying to get this working for hours now.

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by "How to select the files from `DataGridview`", but it is possible to add files o zip from `Stream`. Here is a small code from my application: `ZipArchiveEntry entry = arch.CreateEntry(name); entry.LastWriteTime = new DateTimeOffset(fileInfo.Modified); using (Stream stream = entry.Open()) { fileInfo.SaveFile(stream); stream.Close(); }` And do not forget to delete file when the file already exists in the archive *(only when you are updating the archive)*.

Comment: Break your question to two parts, 1) how to export selected rows of datagridview to text file. 2) how to create zip file from a text file. Then you will find duplicate answers for those questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to save only those files where the `Select` column is checked in your data grid into one zip file.

If so, the following modification to your Zip save routine can help you with that:

```
using (ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipFile, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    List<FileInfo> filesToArchive = new List<FileInfo>();
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderToZip);

    // loop through all of the rows in the data grid
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in XML_Grid.Rows)
    {
        DataRowView rowView = row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
        if (rowView == null) continue; // new row or not bound, ignore
        var selectedValue = rowView["Select"]; // get the value for the select column
        if (selectedValue == DBNull.Value || selectedValue == null || !(bool)selectedValue) // ignore null or false
            continue;

        string fileName = rowView["File_Name"].ToString(); // get the file name
        var files = di.GetFiles(fileName + ".*"); // we had no extension so search the folder to get the full path
        filesToArchive.AddRange(files); // add those file(s) to the list to archive
    }

    if (filesToArchive != null && filesToArchive.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo fileToArchive in filesToArchive)
        {
            zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileToArchive.FullName, fileToArchive.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved me :)

Comment: Multiple rows can have the same filename, at least based on the code used to load the grid. I don't recall offhand what happens if you try to add the same file to the zip multiple times... May have to take precautions against that